# accessing session data

Tags: opencart

I am setting a custom session in the `catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php` controller. All it does, it checks if a value is set or not.

```
if (isset($this->request->post['no_tax']) && $this->request->post['no_tax'] == '1') 
{
   $this->session->data['no_tax'] = true;
} 
elseif (isset($this->request->post['no_tax']) && $this->request->post['no_tax'] === '0') 
{
   unset($this->session->data['no_tax']);
}
```

I can then access this in the `catalog/model/shipping/totalbased.php` model file,

```
isset($this->session->data['no_tax'])
```

The problem is, I need to send additioanl information in the order to the admin, which is done in the `catalog/model/checkout/order.php`

I've done a check in there:

```
if(isset($this->session->data['no_tax']) )
{
   //do something
}
$mail->send();
```

The do something, simply adds a PDF. The problem is, the PDF isn't attached.

In the error.txt, I get: `2012-05-14 14:42:11 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  no_tax in /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/catalog/order.php`

Can I access the session this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine from what I can see, and yes you can access the data like you've shown. The error you've had looks like you have tried to access the session data directly at some point without checking it's set, causing the notice

Comment: I'll have another look at the code and the errors once I've made another test transaction

Comment: I'm wondering, is the following a valid way of attaching a PDF as an attachment: `$mail->addAttachment(DIR_IMAGE.'/pdfs/order.pdf', md5(basename('order.pdf')));` The PDFs are being created using TCPDF and are generated correctly. i.e they are in the pdfs folder. I'm still not getting the PDFs attached.

Comment: Just done a basic if statement to check if the session is actually set. It returned false. `isset($this->session->data['no_tax'])` returned false. Even though it was set.

Comment: Is there another way to check if this session value is set?

Comment: No, that's the proper way to check it. This actually sounds like it's not getting set rather than it not being checked correctly, so I'd start there, and debug if it's actually being set in the first place

Comment: The functioality is similar to your VAT extension. This one however, requires the user to state they are VAT exempt. This then removes the VAT off the product in the cart. It is a simple radio, yes/no. If I say yes and update the cart, VAT is removed. So the session is being set. If I var_dump in any page(header/footer etc) the session value is being output. Just for some unknown reason, the order.php doesn't think it's set. The order.php is part of a vqmod, could this be the problem?

Comment: i.e I have a vqmod that alters the order.php file.

Comment: It could be a problem if it's not matching what it's expected to, or something else is stopping the vqmod from applying, but other than that it should be fine. Best way to check is to have a look at the vqmod.log file

Comment: There's nothing in the vqmod.log file. The vqmod is being applied as when i select 'yes' the VAT is removed from the products. I'm not sure why it always returns false though in the order.php file

Comment: I've had to abandon this for the time being. I can do something similar by checking the db values.